# Do airtags beep if they are traveling with someone who does not have an iThing?

Tags: privacy, geolocation, find-my, airtag

Suppose Brian steels ones bag that has an airbag sewn into it well hidden. Brian doesn't have an iPhone or iPad, but rather a feature phone, or alternately an Android device. He takes it with him on the bus where there are also no iPhones, periodically it drives through junctions, at each of which different people will be hanging out, some of whom have iPhones. The owner needless to say is not on the bus so the tag has been separated from owner.

Obviously Brian can't get stalking notifications on his non existent iPhone but under these circumstances will the airtag emit warning sounds?

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: **Yes**.

Detailed Answer: AirTags will play a sound when they are moved and haven't been connected to their owner for something about 24 hours.

I have one Airtag installed in my car. Although I am the owner and have my iPhone always with me I get to hear the sound quite some times when I have not be driving my car for about a day or so.

Comment: Ok but if you have not been driving your car then it wouldn't have been moving, Would it? And how long/frequently does it beep for?

Comment: It starts beeping as soon as I move my car I guess and does play the sound 2-3 times, in total less than 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Apple makes an android app to ensure people without Apple devices can check if they are near an AirTag that’s not with the owner.

- https://www.theverge.com/2021/12/13/22832731/apple-android-app-airtag-search-tracker-detect-find-my
- https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2022/02/an-update-on-airtag-and-unwanted-tracking/

> AirTag was designed to help people locate their personal belongings, not to track people or another person’s property, and we condemn in the strongest possible terms any malicious use of our products.

In your case Brian may get away with the theft until someone looks for missing AirTags and triggers the warning. Similarly, educated thieves will soon be checking and sanitizing their locations when they steal tracked items.